# document.getElementById данные из первого поля выводит, а из второго нет

Tags: javascript

Не пойму в чем дело. Добиваюсь такого результата: на странице в поле "Введите адрес" впечатывается текст, в поле "Название ЖБК/ОСББ" впечатывается текст, затем нажимается кнопка "Создать" и по результату нажатия кнопки на этой же странице появляется QRкод сформированный из текста введённого поле "Введите адрес", а вот текст, который введён в поле "Название ЖБК/ОСББ" в данный момент на странице не появляется

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Удостоверение</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function create() {
    var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
    document.getElementById("qrimage").innerHTML = "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=" + encodeURIComponent(data) + "'/>";
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var memder = document.getElementById("data").value;
      document.getElementById("memder").innerHTML = memder;
    });
  }
</script>

<body>
  <table border="1" align="center">
    <tr align="center">
      <td align="center">
        <p style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;">Введите адрес:</p>

        &nbsp<textarea cols="40" rows="3" id="data"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td align="center">
        <p style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;">Название ЖБК/ОСББ:</p>
        &nbsp<textarea cols="40" rows="3" id="memder"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <div class="button" onclick="create()">Создать</div>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="qrimage"></div>
  <div id="member"></div>
  <script src="https://notary.coop-ua.org/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Зачем в функции `create` вешать слушатель на событие `DOMContentLoaded`? :-)

Comment: Вопрос должен содержать еще и краткое описание желаемого результата...

Comment: @Air прошу прощения вопрос как бы в теме. А конкретно document.getElementById данные из первого поля выводит, а из второго нет. Что поправить что бы выводились данные и из второго поля?

Comment: может в этой строчке ошибка? `var memder = document.getElementById("data").value;` Может нужно указать `var memder = document.getElementById("memder").value`

Comment: Куда выводит? В QR вы кодируете только одно значение

Comment: Упростил пример до минимума, а щас есть возможность, описать нормально, каков должен быть желаемый результат? И еще, позволь полюбопытствовать, чего именно хотелось бы добиться данной строчкой `document.getElementById("memder").innerHTML = memder;` ?

Comment: @Air добиваюсь такого результата: на странице в поле "Введите адрес" впечатывается текст, в поле "Название ЖБК/ОСББ" впечатывается текст, затем нажимается кнопка "Создать" и по результату нажатия кнопки на этой же странице появляется QRкод сформированый из текста в поле "Введите адрес", а вот текст, который введён в поле "Название ЖБК/ОСББ" в данный момент на странице не появляется. Собственно чего и хочется добиться строчкой document.getElementById("memder").innerHTML = memder; Вот такую задачу не получается решить.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не совсем понял, а как кодировать два значения?

Comment: `а вот текст, который введён в поле "Название ЖБК/ОСББ" в данный момент на странице не появляется.` где он должен появляться?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov вот здесь - <div id="member"></div>

Answer (score 1):

Мембер-шмембер - используйте нормальные идентификаторы для элементов, а не такие, которые отличаются только положением вертикальной палочки в "b"/"d".

```
  function create() {
    var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
    document.getElementById("qrimage").innerHTML = "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=" + encodeURIComponent(data) + "'/>";
    ///!!! document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var memder = document.getElementById("data").value; // то же что и data
      document.getElementById("member").innerHTML = memder; // "member", not "memder"
    ///!!! });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки:

1. Вот этот код

   ```js
   function create() {
     var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
     document.getElementById("qrimage").innerHTML = "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=" + encodeURIComponent(data) + "'/>";
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
       var memder = document.getElementById("data").value;
       document.getElementById("memder").innerHTML = memder;
     });
   }
   ```

   означает:

   1. При нажатии на кнопку взять значение у элемента с `id="data"`, сформировать на основании его QR код и вывести его как картинку
   2. Создать обработчик события `DOMContentLoaded`, который при наступлении события должен будет взять значение у элемента с `id="data"` и вывести его в элемент с id="mem**d**er"

   Т.к событие `DOMContentLoaded` происходит только один раз при загрузке страницы, то установка любого обработчика для этого события **после** загрузки страницы бессмысленна
2. У вас на странице два элемента с id mem**b**er и mem**d**er. Судя по тому, как вы к ним обращаетесь mem**d**er - банальная опечатка
3. Когда вы исправите mem**d**er на mem**b**er, у вас на странице окажутся два элемента с одинаковыми id, что недопустимо стандартами HTML

Если исправить все эти ошибки, то получится вполне работоспособный код

```js
function create() {
  var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
  document.getElementById("qrimage").innerHTML = "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=" + encodeURIComponent(data) + "'/>";
  var member = document.getElementById("member").value;
  document.getElementById("member_show").innerHTML = member;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" align="center">
  <tr align="center">
    <td align="center">
      <p style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;">Введите адрес:</p>
      &nbsp<textarea cols="40" rows="3" id="data"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td align="center">
      <p style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;">Название ЖБК/ОСББ:</p>
      &nbsp<textarea cols="40" rows="3" id="member"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="button" onclick="create()">Создать</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="qrimage"></div>
<div id="member_show"></div>
```